# ¿Cómo agregar y eliminar elementos en un div con Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

¿Como podría hacer para que opere algo como lo que se muestra en esta liga 
[agregar eliminar elementos con javascript](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/archivos3/js_agregar-eliminar-elementos.php) pero en angular? Les comento:

Tengo dos tablas en MySQL empresas y clientes y una que une estas tablas vínculo:

```
vinculo(
   idvinculo int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   idempresa int(11),
   idcliente int(11)
);
```

Y ocupo hacer en Angular algo como se muestra en el link pero que al dar grabar me guarde esta información en la base de datos.

Ya tengo las funciones en una API solo me atore en poder agregar varios clientes a un empresa, cabe mencionar que al entrar al componente de `editarEmpresa`, ya sé que `id` lleva la empresa y me trae los clientes que ya están registrados pero si quiero agregar más o quitarlos ...

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente puedes obtener los datos de las empresas en un Array y luego con el ngFor puedes mostrarlo , igual al agregarlo ejecutas el api de agregar de tu sistema y luego obtienes los nuevos datos agregados y lo guardas en el arreglo, el ngFor esta enlazado al arreglo osea cualquier cambio en el arreglo.

https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

PD: Angular es diferente a Angularjs , Angularjs es la version 1 de Angular , desde la version 2 en adelante solamente se llama Angular ..